# Google login with React and Node.js does not return requested scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, google-api

I need a additional scope data from google api in login in my app. I use `react-google-login` to get token in React app using this scopes:

```
scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read'
```

When I log in with my credentials and allow app to access requested scopes, I successfully get token.

I send this token to backend (Node.js) where I use `google-auth-library` to got payload from token:

```
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library'

export const validateGoogleAccessTokenOAuth2 = async (idToken: string): Promise<any> => {
    const CLIENT_ID = 'MY_ID'
    const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID)

    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken,
        audience: CLIENT_ID
    })
    const payload = ticket.getPayload()

    return payload
}
```

Here I receive only data from profile and email scope, there is no data from requested scopes. Especially I need birthday, I also check it is allowed in my google profile to be accessed by anyone but didn't help.

Is there something what I do wrong or is there another way how to get requested scope variable from token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found that

- birthday and gender attributes are not included in payload of public token
- `client.verifyIdToken` function just verify `idToken` and return its payload
- to get additional information about user, in this case you have to use `People API`

To communicate with People API you can use `googleapis` npm package, also you have to meet this conditions:

- Add `People API` to your project in Google Developer Console
- Add additional scope to your FE call to google (in my case `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read`)
- you have to send `idToken` and `AccessToken` to your backend service
- user have to allow share gender with your application
- user's gender must be set as public in user's google profile

BE example

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library'

export const validateGoogleAccessToken = async (idToken, accessToken) => {
    try {
        const CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID'
        const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID)

        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken,
            audience: CLIENT_ID
        })

        const payload = ticket.getPayload()

        const { OAuth2 } = google.auth
        const oauth2Client = new OAuth2()
        oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: accessToken })

        const peopleAPI = google.people({
            version: 'v1',
            auth: oauth2Client
        })

        const { data } = await peopleAPI.people.get({
            resourceName: 'people/me',
            personFields: 'birthdays,genders',
        })

        const { birthdays, gender } = data

        return {
            ...payload // email, name, tokens
            birthdates, // array of birthdays
            genders, // array of genders
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Google token validation failed')
    }
}
```